# What preposition should come after the word "embarrassment"?

Tags: prepositions

In this line:

> Being too intimate in public places, ignoring social morality and causing **embarrassment of** others.

Should the preposition after "embarrassment" be **"of"** or **"to"**?

Comment: In this particular sentence, "to" works a little better than "of," IMO. Also, it should be "public places" (plural).

Comment: Thanks. I think to is better. But is "of" wrong?

Comment: "causing _the_ embarassment _of_ others", or "causing embarassment _to_ others" (as William says).

Comment: @LouisLiu, "of" is not wrong, although it sounds strange. In my opinion, it is preferable to rewrite the fragment as, "embarrassing others" (rather than "causing embarrassment of others").

Comment: Where is the rest of your sentence?  This could either be the beginning or the end of a **full sentence**.  With a **full sentence**, it's possible that *from* could be more necessary, if not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### embarrassment *to*

The same way as you can *cause*

- **harm** to
- **damage** to
- **danger** to
- **resentment** to
- **pain** to
- **discontent** to

These all have a negative mood to them.  And I can't imagine embarrassment ever being a positive thing either.  The object is **receiving** the action (and effect) of *cause*.